# How would you truncate or limit the results of a date result you are adding time to? (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

So I am doing a homework project where I have to display the current date, and then the date for three months from now, which I have done with this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS "Today's Date", LOWER(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 3)) AS "Today, Three Months Hence" FROM dual;
```

and again with this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS "Today's Date", LOWER(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '3' MONTH)AS "Today, Three Months Hence" FROM dual;
```

results:

`Today's Date`

`05-FEB-14`

`Today, Three Months Hence`
 `05-may-14`

What I am wondering is if there is a way to display the results of the future date where it only shows the month and nothing else, (i.e. no day or year). Is this possible in Oracle, or am I just looking to try the impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the display format, which you should really do anyway instead of relying on your session defaults:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Today's Date",
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 3), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AS "Today, Three Months Hence",
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 3), 'Month') AS "Three Months Hence"
FROM dual;

| TODAY'S DATE | TODAY, THREE MONTHS HENCE | THREE MONTHS HENCE |
|--------------|---------------------------|--------------------|
|   06/02/2014 |                2014-05-06 |          May       |
```

Simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24849).

The available date format model elements are shown [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i34924).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure it out after seeing someone using a to_char to only display the part of the date they wanted. What was really getting me stuck at that point was that I still had to use the lower function to make the result print out in lower case, but I realized, (by accident), that if you type month in lower case, it will print out in lower case. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A `date` value is actually stored as a number in database, not a character string. What you see in your result is the default date format interpretation of your session.

To change the way your date fields are displayed, you need to use `to_char` function.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MM') from dual;
```

`'MM'` parameter here stands for month, which is what you asked. It is a format string to convert a date into a character string. For a list of your options with format string, a simple google search will help you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was looking at an example about to_char and finally sorted it out:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS "Today's Date", TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 3), 'month') AS "Today, Three Months Hence" FROM dual;
```

This is similar to the answer provided by Alex. I did notice that when I type in month in lower case the result is also in lower case, and when it type it in as MONTH, in upper case, the result is then in upper case, which is good to know. This wasn't required, but I was curious.
[image: Result Table]

Comment: Yes, that's mentioned in the doc I linked to, in the section 'Uppercase Letters in Date Format Elements'.